# Trigger VSTS/TFS build with webhook from Bit Bucket

Tags: tfs, bitbucket, tfsbuild

UPDATE: This is old question. TFS now fully support integration with Bitbucket!

Is it really not possible to trigger build in TFS/VSTS 2015 from outside with http?

I have repository on BitBucket and I want to trigger build on commit.
I have searched the web and found nothing.

Comment: Check this out - https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/repository#external-git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unless you use a third party service like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/bitbucket/visual-studio-online/).

There is already a user voice submitted for this. check this link for details: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/10674648-enable-ci-build-support-for-bitbucket-git-reposito

**Update:**
This feature is available in VSTS now. You can choose "BitBucket" as the "Srouce" and enable the trigger under "Triggers" panel.

Comment: I hope it will be added soon but I doubt it as there are only 9 votes.
I thought this is a must feature but it looks like I am an edge case.

Comment: Ok, I tried Zapier and the method they advertise is checking BitBucket for changes every 5 minutes and triggering build for every changeset in case push has several changesets. Not good.
There is better way:
On Zapier choose 'Webhooks by Zapier'. Then create webhook in Bitbucker repository settings and set url to one provided by Zapier.
Instant builds!

(but I have another unrelated problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841780/vsts-build-failes-when-triggered-by-zapier)

Answer (score 3):

The trigger setting in VSTS build definition doesn't work properly with external repositories. Basically a user needs to login to the VSTS account and then the trigger checks the repository.

You can create an Azure Function and use that as your BitBucket Webhook. Then inside the Azure Function use [VSTS REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds) to trigger the build.

Below is the code that you can paste in your Azure Function and after setting

- instance name
- project name
- definition Id(s)
- branch name(s)
- personal access token

it will just work the way you want -> Right after you push a commit to the repository, it will queue a build for the specified definition.

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
  var definitionId = -1;

  dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
  var branch = data?.push?.changes[0]?.@new?.name;

  if(branch == "master") definitionId = 6; // TODO update the branch name and definition Id to match your settings
  else if(branch == "ci/website-staging") definitionId = 7; // TODO update the branch name and definition Id to match your settings

  if (definitionId >= 0) // Known branch
  {
      string accessToken = GetEnvironmentVariable("PersonalAccessToken"); // TODO add your personal token to your app settings or paste it here
      const string instance = "instance_name"; // TODO put the instance name
      const string project = "project_name"; // TODO put the project name
      const string version = "api-version=2.0";

      var url = $"https://{instance}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds?{version}";
      var authorizationToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{accessToken}"));
      var body = "{\"definition\" : {\"id\" : " + definitionId + "}}";

      return await PostAsync(url, body, authorizationToken);
  }

  return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string url, string jsonBody, string authorizationToken = null)
{
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationToken))
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authorizationToken);
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
      var content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      return await client.PostAsync("", content);
  }
}

private static string GetEnvironmentVariable(string name)
{
  return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(name, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
}
```

I've written a detailed [blog post](http://async.codes/trigger-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-ci-build-from-bitbucket/) about it in case you need more info.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Zapier with webhook and currently it works great!

Answer (score 0):

---

**Update** - TFS now offers bitbucket integration

---

This is quite old thread, still - tfs documentation has this link to follow: https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/repository#external-git

See this snap: 
[image]

#### Triggering build whenever certain branch is updated:

After linking to your repository, go back to your build definition, and select *Triggers* tab.

From here you can trigger your TFS build definition whenever repository branch is updated.

1. Check the Continuous Integration (CI) checkbox
2. Click the `+ Add new Filter` link to add new trigger and insert the branch name to the textbox.
3. Add new filter on other branch you wand to trigger (include) or exclude branches from CI process (select Exclude in listbox)
   [image]

   - This is the full blog post discussing linking to external git repository:
     http://saturn72.com/wp/blog/2016/08/15/connect-tfs-to-bitbucket-repository/
   - Instructions how to add triggers: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers

Comment: Problem is not building from external git but triggering build on external git commit

Comment: The "problematic" part is to link to external repo. Triggering the build on commit is done like any other triggering (I Added this part at the end of the answer above).

Comment: CI is not supported with external git.
Written in docs and confirmed by support.

Comment: @hex our TFS build server is integrates with bitbucket git code repository for several months now with no issue what so ever. Also I found it odd there is ability to integrate with external git servers while this feature not supported

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently where anything I pushed to my external Bitbucket did not trigger my VSTS builds.

I found the values in the git attributes **user.email** & **user.name** on my local Repo were not the same as the external Bitbucket.

To fix this issue go to your Repo in Bitbucket.

1. Open the Settings of the Repo
2. Under **General** select **Username aliases**
3. Type in your **name** for Bitbucket and the email from the **user.email** git attribute from your local Repo.