# VSTS Build failes when triggered by Zapier

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, zapier

I have build definition that builds using VSBuild.
When triggered from web interface it works perfectly.
But when triggered from Zapier it fails with following error:

> [error]C:\TFSAgent_work\1\s\CityExpert.sln.metaproj(0,0): Error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "CRMDev|any cpu" is
>   invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the
>   Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln
>   /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those
>   properties blank to use the default solution configuration.

But that configuration is in solution and is the same the manualy queued build uses.
All configuration is the same, brench is the same. MSBuild command line switches in log - same.

Comment: Does the build success if you queue the build from VSO manually? As I know, Zapier just trigger the build, does not send any information related to build. The configuration should be set in VSO build definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
It looks like a bug in VSTS.

Builds from Zapier are pulling master breach even when other one is configured as default.

Build details show 'devel' as default breach:

```
Build details
Definition CRMDev (edit)
Source branch devel
Source version
Requested by Boris Prpic
Queued Monday, January 18, 2016 7:42:41 PM
Started Monday, January 18, 2016 7:42:45 PM
Finished Monday, January 18, 2016 7:42:51 PM
```

But the logs show it is really pulling master:

```
2016-01-18T19:42:32.3257942Z Syncing repository: CRM (Git)
2016-01-18T19:42:32.3559010Z Starting fetch
2016-01-18T19:42:34.5759230Z Checking out refs/remotes/origin/master to C:\TFSAgent\_work\1\s
2016-01-18T19:42:34.6471116Z Checked out branch  for repository CRM at commit 40fe14218f9d6b7cfcf7e28fbd0cef507e6d37f6
```

Comment: For VSTS build, the build branch has been configured in the build definition, Zapier only trigger the build, cannot update the branch settings in VSTS build definition. So for your case, you need to create several VSTS build definitions for different branches. And in Zapier Step 4, add filter for branch to trigger the corresponding build definition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood. Problem is that Zapier triggered build is always building from master. It does not respect what is configured in build definition.

Comment: Can you tell me which Zapier integration you are using to trigger builds.

Comment: VSTS Integration, Trigger Build action.

For Triggers I first used Bitbucket integration new event trigger.
Now I use web hooks integration for trigger because it's faster.
Both triggers have a problem.